# select rows based on month part in ms access database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, ms-access

I have  a table in ms access 2007.The table contains 10 rows .The table contains a date column.
There are rows having date as-21-07-2014,25-07-2014..

When selecting i want to get 25-07-2014.That is only one row on that month on that year..

I have to select the rows that have different month/year part in date field.That is,when selecting the rows,I want to select single row from multiple rows based on the month and year part of date_field.

Please help me..I have tried different queries..But nothing worked.
eg:

SELECT DISTINCT (DATE_FIELD),ID_PK_FIELD,AMOUNT_FIELD,DATE_FIELD FROM TBL_MONTH WHERE MON__STRE__FK= ? ORDER BY DATE_FIELD DESC

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Comment: Could you please edit your post, by adding some sample data and along with the result you like to see. Your description is not making much sense.

Comment: `Month()`, `DAY()`, `Year()` are all functions to obtain the respective data. http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/format.php

Comment: Actually,the above query not working...I am getting all the rows

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(DATE_FIELD),ID_PK_FIELD,AMOUNT_FIELD,DATE_FIELD FROM TBL_MONTH WHERE MON__STRE__FK= ? ORDER BY DATE_FIELD DESC ; also not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use the follwing;

Get the highest date within a month/year combination;

```
SELECT Max(dates.datefield) AS MaxOfdatefield, DatePart("m",[datefield]) AS [Month], DatePart("yyyy",[datefield]) AS [Year]
FROM dates
GROUP BY DatePart("m",[datefield]), DatePart("yyyy",[datefield]);
```